# CodeIgniter Ajax Layer

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, object

I've been doing a lot of researching on ajax but I cant seem to find much about creating a separate ajax layer with codeigniter... I've seen ajax controllers in the directory tree of people performing tutorial videos on codeigniter, just never gotten a real explanation. I'm assuming its to promote encapsulation and to show only to users with javascript enabled and such, just not sure how to go about implementing it in a controller for use in my own projects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It all depends on what you're doing. The easiest way, in my opinion, is not to have separate AJAX controllers and urls, but to detect the request in your controller and output something different than you normally would. The [Input class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html) has a function for this:

```
/**
 * Is ajax Request?
 *
 * Test to see if a request contains the HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH header
 *
 * @return  boolean
 */
public function is_ajax_request()
{
    return ($this->server('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH') === 'XMLHttpRequest');
}
```

I prefer to use a constant:

```
/**
 * Is this an ajax request?
 *
 * @return      bool
 */
define('AJAX', isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] === 'XMLHttpRequest');
```

Example usage in a controller method:

```
$data = $this->some_model->get();
if ($this->input->is_ajax_request())
{
    // AJAX request stops here
    exit(json_encode($data));
}
$this->load->view('my_view', $data);
```

This way, you don't have identical or similar application logic spread out through sevral different controllers, and your code can be more maintainable. For example, your standard HTML forms can post to the same location with AJAX and have different output, so it also helps make [progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) easier and cleaner. In addition, you won't have "AJAX-only" URLs that you need to "hide" from the user.

Answer (score 0):

I will attempt to offer a simple solution that I have used in the past.  I am however, uncertain about your proficieny/familiarity with CodeIgniter, also this is my own "home-brewed" solution that I developed to deal with the issues in CodeIgniter.

I like CodeIgniter for its simplicity, and small foot print.  But certain of its features I don't use: I don't use the provided database connection system, as I am a little bit of a control freak and SQL injection is so prevalent.  So I have learned how to deviate within the framework for this reason.

In order to create a separate "layer" that houses AJAX processing and to keep it clean and tidy in implementation I just make a separate controller object who's specific job is to respond to AJAX requests.  This way your "web page" controllers are separate from your "Ajax" controllers.

```
class Ajax extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct(){ parent::__construct();}
    function webserv(){ /* Your Web Service code here... */}
}
```

Then you would direct your AJAX requests to this URL:

> http://www.example.com/ajax/webserv/

Comment: So, *all* the ajax functionality of your site is packed into one monstrous controller? Seems like it would be quite a mess as your application grows. Either that, or you aren't using AJAX for much.

Comment: @Madmartigan we meet again.  It depends on the application -- I use AJAX in certain circumstances for specific reasons, so if I have say 7 or less AJAX calls for the entire website, yeah I will group them into one "monolithic" AJAX controller, else if I am doing a web application that is AJAX rich I just set up a parallel system of Ajax controllers, where it is a 1:1 ratio between page controllers and ajax controllers

Comment: Yeah I thought I recognized the name/avatar, where/when do I know you from?

Comment: @Madmartigan I got mad at you once when you called me on the carpet for a post I did in the past, the post was not high quality/helpful and I got embarrassed and acted like a jerk. Apologies to you for being a d-bag. I've since learned some humility.

Comment: Hey it's all good man, attitudes can come out sometimes but we all mean the best. I probably sounded like a jerk myself, this place has helped me learn to act/write more professionally. My first few months here I may have been a bit snippy.